# What should be Content-Type if response is encrypted json?

Tags: rest, http-headers, content-type

What should be `Content-Type` header, for a REST web service response which contains encrypted JSON in body?

Here encrypted JSON does not mean JOSE or JWE. It is symmetric encryption done by interceptor, using any algorithm. Is it okay if I keep `application/json` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [RFC1847](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1847#section-2.2) you should use multipart/encrypted. You then have to provide information about the encrypted and unencrypted data formats in the two required body parts.

Example from the RFC:

```
Content-Type: multipart/encrypted; protocol="TYPE/STYPE";
        boundary="Encrypted Boundary"

--Encrypted Boundary
Content-Type: TYPE/STYPE

CONTROL INFORMATION for protocol "TYPE/STYPE" would be here

--Encrypted Boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

    Content-Type: application/json
```